# Does PHP usort() work on DOM nodeLists?

Tags: php, sorting, nodelist

I have a bunch of data stored in an XML file that I print out as a list with PHP. I want the user to be able to choose how to sort the list.

I experimented a bit with `usort()`, but it doesn't seem to be working. It doesn't throw an exception, so I'm thinking that it is doable, but there's something amiss with my sorting function. The first thing I want to do is let the data be sorted by the date it was created - this is stored in an attribute like this:

```
<root>
    <info created="2011-12-31">
        <sometags />
    </info>
    <info created="2012-01-02">
        <sometags />
    </info>
    <info created="2012-01-01">
        <sometags />
    </info>
</root>
```

and my sorting is done with this:

```
function sortByDate($a, $b) {

    //get array of year, month and day
    $adates = explode('-', $a->getAttribute('created'));
    $bdates = explode('-', $b->getAttribute('created'));

    //if the years are not the same, use them to sort
    if ($adates[0] != $bdates[0]) {
        return (intval($adates[0]) < intval($bdates[0])) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    //if the years are the same, try sorting by the months
    else if ($adates[1] != $bdates[1]) {
        return (intval($adates[1]) < intval($bdates[1])) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    //if the years and months are both the same, try sorting by days
    else {
        return (intval($adates[2]) < intval($bdates[2])) ? -1 : 1;
    }

    //if we get this far, the dates are identical
    return 0;
}
```

and this is how I call it:

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load('data.xml');

$infotags = $xmlDoc->documentElement->getElementsByTagName('info');

usort($infotags, 'sortByDate');
```

Is it some silly error I've made, or should I be doing something else entirely?

By the way, I'm aware that the `if... else` construct above won't actually sort the dates in the proper order. I'm just trying to get it to do *something* - at the moment `usort()` just leaves the nodelist in the same order it was to begin with.

Comment: have you checked any of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sort+xml+php before asking? If so, please point out why none of these answered your question.

Comment: Agh, you're right. I was searching with "nodelist" which seems to have filtered out a lot of relevant results. XSLT seems to be the way I should go. Sorry, I'll try to search more effectively next time. Should I delete this question...?

Comment: well, if the search results answer your question, then yeah, i'd delete it. not sure if you can with @Sjoerd having given an answer though.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a DOMNodeList, which is an Iterator and not a real array. Therefore, you can not change the order of the list.

Try converting it to an array first.

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks, I'll see what I can come up with.